# Given action, reducer returned undefined

Tags: reactjs, cross-domain, axios

I'm doing my first react.js app. Because of some issues with the react & redux template project in Visual Studio 2017 I ended up with a Web API in Visual Studio 2017 and a whole different react project in Visual Studio Code (I don't know if that is relevant). I'm trying to consume my Web API but my action.payload.data is always undefined. Also I get a cross-origin error. I don't get what am I doing wrong.

***src/actions/index.js***

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_HOME = 'fetch_home';

const R00T_URL = 'http://localhost:52988/api';

export function fetchHome() {
    const request = axios.get(`${R00T_URL}/home`, { crossdomain: true });

    console.log(`request: ${request}`);
    return {
        type: FETCH_HOME,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

***src/reducers/reducer_home.js***

```
import { FETCH_HOME } from '../actions';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    if (typeof action.payload === 'undefined') {
        console.log('action undefined');
        return state;
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_HOME:            
            console.log(`action: ${action}`);
            return action.payload.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

***src/components/home_index.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchHome } from '../actions';

class HomeIndex extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchHome();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(`props: ${this.props}`);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Home Index</h1>                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { props: state.props };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchHome })(HomeIndex);
```

***src/index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import reducers from './reducers';
import HomeIndex from './components/home_index';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={HomeIndex} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

[image: pending promise]

[image: console log for index.js]

[image: i do am able to access the api data]

Comment: instead of just returning `return action.payload.data` its good idea to return a fresh state `return { ...state , action.payload.data}` and try without "undefined" as it will fall to default which will result in the same state being returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to **axios.get()** is asynchronous.

You likely want your action creator to return the action object, like this:

***src/actions/index.js***

```
...

export function fetchHome(result) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_HOME,
    payload: result
  }
}
```

...and then perform the async request in your component and call the action creator with the results:

***src/components/home_index.js***

```
...

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`${R00T_URL}/home`, { crossdomain: true })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`result: ${result}`);
      this.props.fetchHome(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Handle error
    })
}

...
```

If you want to keep the async part in your action creator then look at using **redux-thunk**:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. I'm looking forward to integrate thunk in the future.